# jQuery UI Slider customization not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, uislider

I am trying to create a customized jQuery slider. For that, I need to change the background of the slider handle. So I tried out this code at http://jsfiddle.net/Cupidvogel/gdfgv/.

As per the documentation, I have included an element with class `ui-slider-handle` inside the slider, and am trying to set the style on that. But the background of the handle is still not changing. Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you didn't close the paranthesis after the div#slider-range-min { background: yellow !important;} <---

Comment: Insanely dumb and careless of me...

Answer (score 0):

u have not close the parathesis in div#slider-range-min,
so use

> div.ui-slider-range-min `{ background: green !important; }`
>
> > div#slider-range-min `{ background: yellow !important; }`
> >
> > > div#slider-range-min div.ui-slider-handle `{ background: red;  }`
> > >
> > > > in your css